# What is wrong with my integration? Finding expected value. Statistics

Tags: calculus, integration

I am aware that I could have equally used the Beta distribution but I just wanted to check where in my solution did it go wrong.

I wanted to solve $I=\int_{0}^{1}x^r(1-x)^{n-r}dx$ where $n$ and $r$ are both integers. I shall proceed this with integration by parts.

**My thoughts**

Let $\frac{dv}{dx}=1$ and $u=x^r(1-x)^{n-r}$. We shall have that $\frac{du}{dx}=rx^{r-1}(1-x)^{n-r}-(n-r)x^r(1-x)^{n-r-1}$ and $v=x$.

So we have $I=\int_{0}^{1}x^r(1-x)^{n-r}dx$=$-\int_{0}^{1}rx^{r}(1-x)^{n-r}-(n-r)x^{r+1}(1-x)^{n-r-1}dx=-rI+\int_{0}^{1}(n-r)x^{r+1}(1-x)^{n-r-1}dx$.

I noticed that $\int_{0}^{1}x^{r+1}(1-x)^{n-r-1}dx=I$ if we do a transformation by $m=r+1$, say. Hence I deduced, $I=-rI+(n-r)I$. Then I am stuck at this point, I couldn't find the value of $I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely, if we write $I_{n,\,r}=\int_0^1x^r(1-x)^{n-r}dx$ you've shown $I_{n,\,r+1}=\frac{r+1}{n-r}I_{n,\,r}$. Using $I_{n,\,0}=\int_0^1(1-x)^ndx=\frac{1}{n+1}$, you should be able to induct on $r$ to prove $I_{n,\,r}=\frac{r!(n-r)!}{(n+1)!}$ for $r\le n$.